# Unexplained scrot screenshots

Tags: bash, screenshot

First, about a week ago, i saw a series of screenshot files attributed to `scrot` separated by a second in my home directory, e.g. `2016-06-25-02030[1-9]`. I was working on something that required me to frequently reboot at the time. I did not use the `scrot` bash command.

Now, over the last three days, I see three more `scrot` files, and I've not used `scrot` over the last few days. I see no keyboard shortcuts for `scrot`. I see no easy way to take a screenshot in raspbian, using `scrot` as the default application. It looks like I have no related bash aliases. What could it be?

Comment: have you checked your `crontab` entries?

Comment: nothing related in the `crontab`

Comment: Look at the header of the files. Are there some hints in them?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by file headers and how should I access those?

Comment: image sizes were all for full desktop

Comment: It appears the headers for every file are the same as in the example at the `png` [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a cat? Could it have accidentally walked over the keyboard and hit the **Prt Sc** key?

Raspbian's GUI sets up the Print Screen key to call `scrot` by default. Check the config file `.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml` to see if it has any references to the command.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already changed the default password and disconnected from the Internet, start there. If the scrot captures continue check /etc/rc.local for odd entries.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Bluetooth num/keypad (not a full keyboard) with all keys mapped specific to my app and with stickers on top of them. And I also started to notice lots of screenshots in my home directory. Then I realised that one of the keys I have mapped in my app is actually a print screen key on this Bluetooth physical keyboard! If you by any chance have an odd keyboard with such key that could be the explanation.

I stumbled across this post while looking for a way to disable this because I really want to use that key for something else in my app. The config file mentioned in one of the other answers doesn't exist on my Raspbian.

I did not find where to disable the mapping of print screen to `scrot`, however in https://askubuntu.com/questions/279496/how-to-disable-print-screen-shortcut the second answer suggests just replacing the screenshotting binary with an empty bash script which is what I did.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/scrot /usr/bin/scrot.bak
```

Create new file `/usr/bin/scrot` with following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then change ownership

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/scrot
```

Answer (score 0):

as of scrot, open/edit .config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml

replace scrot with (single line)

```
scrot -q 1 '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_$wx$h_scrot.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/Screencaps/'
```

(or whatever directory you like)

and you have a handy screenshot dairy preventing scrot from overwriting and cluttering up the home dir.